# Getting an error in LWC while using field schema if org's namespace name & field name is same

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

For example, my org's namespace is **abc**. & on **Account** object I have a field named **abc__c**. Now when I am trying to import field schema in lwc as below,

```
import ABC_FIELD from '@Salesforce/schema/Account.abc__c';
```

then it throw an error like this,

```
Invalid module id "Account.abc__c" for type "schema". Explicit use of namespace "abc" in file "validateFormLwc.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.
```

Is this lwc issue. Any solution on this please.

Comment: Did you try ```import ABC_FIELD from '@Salesforce/schema/abc_Account.abc__c```

Comment: Yes, tried but same result